# Outlook 2013 / Windows 8.1: Delete e-mail from notification toast

Tags: windows-8.1, microsoft-outlook-2013

I've got Microsoft Office 2013 Service Pack 1 running on my Windows 8.1 (with Update 1) laptop, which is a Dell Latitude E6430.

In previous versions of Windows + Office, you could delete an e-mail when the semi-transparent "new e-mail" notification popped up, in the lower right-hand corner of the screen. With Microsoft Office  2013 on Winodws 8.1, this does not appear to be possible.

Does anyone know if there's a way to delete an e-mail from the notification toast that pops up on Windows 8.1?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, it seems that this feature has gone... Now there's only a poor notification, without any possible interaction. You can check this add-in, it's not beautiful, but it does the job : https://outlook2013addin.codeplex.com

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The solution as explained [here](http://consultantsrus.blogspot.fr/2015/03/outlook-2013-windows-8-desktop-alerts.html) is to run Outlook in Vista compatibility mode.

Find the location of the file OUTLOOK.EXE (not its shortcut, the real file), something like: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16` then:

- Either right-click on the file => Properties => Compatibility, Select "Run in Windows Vista (Service Pack 2) mode"
- Or if (like me) the tab "Compatibility" doesn't exist, right-click on the file => Troubleshoot compatibility => Troubleshoot program => I can't see my problem listed => Window Vista SP2 => I can't see my problem listed => test the program => next => Yes, save these settings

Et voilà !

Comment: The problem with this solution is Outlook always needs Admin rights to launch and search mails doesn't seem to work.

Comment: For those looking for a Windows 10 solution: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/c3054385-c30e-42b0-89b9-1e6b5a05b383/instantly-delete-arriving-email-message-from-notification-windows-10?forum=outlook