# What happened to the delete button on Outlook new email notification popups in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

In Windows 7, the *new email* notification that appears near the Windows taskbar (near *running tasks* section) contains an "X" that allows you to immediately delete an email message from the notification.  In Windows 8, the notification still appears, but it no longer has the delete button.

Is there a registry setting, or an option from w/in Outlook that can enable deletions?

Comment: If my memory serves me correctly, its not windows 8 that changed this, but outlook 2013.

Comment: I just checked and Outlook 2013 in Windows 7 still has it.

Comment: Have you seen http://superuser.com/questions/783985/outlook-2013-windows-8-1-delete-e-mail-from-notification-toast?

Comment: No I didn't and I did my due diligence in searching google and SO. It wasn't even a suggested question despite the similarity. Despite that, I don't see why this question received a downvote.

Comment: I have selected it as a duplicate — thank you, Lance and Karan.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this has been removed in Outlook 2013, but I'm not sure that's accurate.  My Outlook is listed as 2013 in the *about* dialog and still has this feature in Windows 7.

That said, this post mentions that the feature was dropped in 2013:
https://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/blog/Bringing-some-Outlook-2010-features-into-2013-with-the-add-in